# New > Individual Mandatory Phone

Tags: joomla, civicrm-home, phone

When creating an individual record, how do I make the phone number field a mandatory field. I mean, I don't want a record before the phone number is written.

`administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/contact/add&ct=Individual&reset=1`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are wanting to require a phone number when some contributes, becomes a member, or registers for an event.

Go to Admin > Custom Data > Profiles

Look for the Profile that you will be using in your Event/Contribution pages and to the right click Fields

You can edit the Phone field and make it Required

Comment: I'm not talking about adding private data. You already have a phone option on the screen. I want to be obligatory In the same way, your name and surname can also be information.

A photo can be more descriptive added.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean here? If you want to make the field required you will have to create a little extension and use the buildForm hook. You can not do this in the UI AFAIK.

Comment: Iowa Boy is right in the sense that if you want to make phone mandatory then instead of using New Individual you could use a Profile for adding contacts. DOesn't prevent folk not using the Profile though if they have access to the backend. But from the question it is not nec. clear if this is to ensure no record is EVER created without a phone, or if this is only a requirement in certain circumstances. Perhaps this Answer could be improved by suggesting use of a standalone profile in create mode?

Comment: Faith - I don't understand your 'not talking about private data' comment. probably a translation issue. if you could add some more to your Question about what situations you want to 'force' a phone number to be added it would help folk help you.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this. Let me start with these sentences.
I don't want the recording to be created without adding a phone number.
I would like to make the new number on the individual form is mandatory.

Comment: What page do you want the mandatory phone field on? Is it on a public contribution page or is it in the backend under Contacts > New Individual?